# Try-Except Behavior

Tags: python

```
import sys  

def checkarg():  
    try:  
        filename=str(sys.argv[1])  
        if filename=="-mycommand":  
            print "SPECIFIC_TEXT"  
            sys.exit()  
        else:    
            return filename  
    except:  
        print "ERROR"  
        sys.exit()
```

Hello all...i have a problem with the code above. When i call the 'checkarg' function, if i did not pass any parameter on the command line i have the "ERROR" output and sys exit, just as expected.

But, if i provide a parameter on the command line (like "-mycommand") it prints the "SPECIFIC_TEXT" and then prints "ERROR" message from the EXCEPT block too.

The TRY block will only run when I provide a parameter, if I don't, then EXCEPT will get the turn. But, it is running the TRY and EXCEPT blocks together.

Does anybody knows the reason of this behavior?? Any mistake on my code? Tks for all !

Comment: Maybe the problem is all the asterisks?

Comment: Fixed up the formatting for him.

Comment: As an aside, why `str(sys.argv[1])`?  Isn't sys.argv[1] already a string?

Comment: Sorry for that, and thanks for the fix !

Comment: DSM, i did not check it, but probably yes. I just put that to force this step and avoid another erros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand your question...

`sys.exit()` exits by raising a SystemExit exception, which your except statement is catching.

Comment: So, it runs the TRY block and when faces the sys.exit() it changes to EXCEPT block, because the SystemExit exception. So, in the practice it runs the both blocks. Thats right???

Answer (score 4):

Answer found here: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

> *sys.exit([arg])*
>
> Exit from Python. **This is implemented by raising the SystemExit exception**, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.

`sys.exit` works by raising an exception. That's why your except block executes.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using `try`/`except` for situations where you can check the state using control flow logic.

Instead, in this case, check for if `len(sys.argv) > 1`.

Another reason never to use specifically a blank `except`: You will catch even system exceptions like `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt`, making it potentially impossible to terminate your program short of a messy kill.

Comment: Tks for the recommendation. I changed the except to catch only the stuff I need. Tks again ! @Platinum

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I think the root of the problem is that your `try` block contains code in which you do not necessarily wish to catch exceptions; rather, you merely wish these statements to be executed *after* the code in which you wish to catch exceptions if no exception occurs.

To address this, your `try` block should contain only `filename=str(sys.argv[1])` and the rest of the code now in your `try` block should be moved to an `else` block, which will be executed only if no exception occurs. In other words:

```
try:  
    filename=str(sys.argv[1])  
except:  
    print "ERROR"  
    sys.exit()
else:
    if filename=="-mycommand":  
        print "SPECIFIC_TEXT"  
        sys.exit()  
    else:    
        return filename
```

Or in this case, since you exit the script entirely in the case of an exception, you don't actually need the `else`:

```
try:  
    filename=str(sys.argv[1])  
except:  
    print "ERROR"  
    sys.exit()
if filename=="-mycommand":  
    print "SPECIFIC_TEXT"  
    sys.exit()  
else:    
    return filename
```

The fact that you're catching every exception with your bare `except` is bad style and changing that would also avoid the problem, but to me, it's secondary. You do not wish to catch exceptions in your `if/else` code, so it should not be in the `try` block to begin with. IMHO, most admonitions against bare `except` would be moot if this guideline were followed more closely.